# How do you use setInitialMenuItem for Google Glass menus, and do you have example code?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Google Glass online documentation mentions the method but with minimal documentation:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/view/MenuUtils

Should this be called from `onOptionsItemSelected` or `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Any example code would be most appreciated.

Comment: Would someone be willing to share example code that implements this method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this method from `onCreateOptionsMenu` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in order to set the menu item that will be initially visible when the user asks for the menu to be displayed. If you call it from `onOptionsItemSelected`, then it will be too late, since the menu was already displayed and interacted with.